# Cannot resolve Zendesk library

Tags: android, gradle, zendesk

In one moment, our integration with zendesk stopped working, even on old stable builds
Error is:

```
Could not find com.zendesk:support:3.0.3.
```

Repositories for my module is configured as documentation said before dependencies:

```
repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    name 'Google'
}
maven {
    url "https://linphone.org/releases/maven_repository/"
}
maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
```

}

And here is dependency

```
implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'support', version: '3.0.3'
```

Full error:

```
> Could not find com.zendesk:support:3.0.3.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - file:/Users/user/waytoproj/libs/support-3.0.3.jar
   - file:/Users/user/waytoproj/libs/support.jar
   - https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - https://jitpack.io/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - https://jitpack.io/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - https://linphone.org/releases/maven_repository/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - https://linphone.org/releases/maven_repository/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/zendesk/support/3.0.3/support-3.0.3.jar
```

And, as I said, old successed builds also gonna broken, after rebuild. So looks like it's some problem with repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer
In main application module, I found another repository:

```
maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
```

I guess it have some problems and doesn't work this moment

Comment: The zendesk repo is changed to `https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo` (source: https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360043755634-Failed-to-resolve-com-zopim-android-sdk-1-3-6-1) I've got a 'not resolved' error when build on android.